# How to join two tables based on two different conditions in R?

Tags: r, left-join

I would like to perform left join on two different tables but based on two different conditions. First condition is that the id should match and next condition is the time. And the result of the join should be combination of both conditions but in the specific order.

Example:

Table1

```
COUNTRY ID  TIME    VALUE
2   198 01-01-2014 00:00    18
2   198 01-01-2014 00:30    17
2   198 01-01-2014 01:00    16
2   147 01-01-2014 00:00    18
2   147 01-01-2014 00:30    19
2   147 01-01-2014 01:00    20
2   142 01-01-2014 00:00    22
2   142 01-01-2014 00:30    25
```

Table2

```
COUNTRY IDENTITY    TIME_UTC    AMOUNT
2   198 01-01-2014 00:00    2
2   198 01-01-2014 00:30    5
2   198 01-01-2014 01:00    2
2   147 01-01-2014 00:00    6
2   147 01-01-2014 00:30    3
2   147 01-01-2014 01:00    4
```

I now want to left join Table1 and Table2. First condition match Columns ID and IDENTITY and then columns TIME and TIME_UTC.

Comment: You probably want to check `merge` command. Try `?merge` on the console.

Comment: merge(Table1, Table2, by.x = ("ID" & "IDENTITY"), by.y = ("TIME" & "TIME_UTC"), all.x = TRUE). I get the error:  Error in "ID" & "IDENTITY" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types. I am not sure how to pass two arguements to the by function.

Comment: `by.x` should be passed column names of Table 1. try `merge(table1, table2, by.x=c("ID", "TIME"), by.y = c("IDENTITY", "TIME_UTC"), all=T)`

Comment: Using the merge(table1, table2, by.x=c("ID", "TIME"), by.y = c("IDENTITY", "TIME_UTC"), all=T) it works. But out of curiosity I tried the left_join. left_join(Table1, Table2, by.x = c("ID", "TIME"), by.y = c("IDENTITY", "TIME_UTC"), all = TRUE). But it threw an error :
Joining by: "IDENTITY"
Error: POSIXlt not supported.. Is this due to data type issues? Both the values in ID and IDENTITY are of int type.

Comment: From which package did you get `left_join`? I don't seem to have it in `base`

Comment: left_join is from the package dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

You can first left join Table1 and Table 2 with Columns ID (using dplyr or data.table) and then filter the results to make sure it only keeps rows that have equal columns TIME and TIME_UTC.